# A simple Sinatra/Ruby substitution

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In Sinatra I have simple helper to return a symbol:

```
def sort_column
  params[:sort] ? params[:sort].to_sym : :client_id
end
```

that my Booking is ordered by:

```
get '/bookings' do
  @bookings = Booking.all(order: sort_column)
  erb :bookings
end
```

I'd like my Booking to be ordered asc or desc depending on the output of another helper:

```
def sort_direction
  params[:direction] || "asc"
end
```

This:

```
@bookings = Booking.all(order: sort_column.asc)
```

and this:

```
@bookings = Booking.all(order: sort_column.desc)
```

both work fine.

But if I use:

```
@bookings = Booking.all(order: sort_column.sort_direction)
```

I get a private method error, and if I try to:

```
@bookings = Booking.all(order: sort_column + "." + sort_direction)
```

I get an "undefined method '+' for ... " error

How do I substitute in the result of sort_direction to determine whether the Booking is ordered asc or desc?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Booking.all(order: sort_column.send(sort_direction))
```

Comment: That was such a swift response Kyle that I can't even accept your answer for another 10 minutes. Thanks.

Comment: Yes thank you.. I had never used/heard of send() but looked it up before plugging it into my code (http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send)